# Failed to open directory Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have recently created a HelloWorld project with Xamarin Forms to develop a mobile app. But, I don't know what happen but I cannot launch the app with Android Device Manager or even my own phone, not even the first time. This is the error:

[image]

I am using android version 10.0 to compile and for the device manager the version 10.0 also. At the manifest I also have version 10.0 for Android minimum version required and Android target version. I guess the version is not the problem, but I don't know what could be because, I haven't programmed anything yet. So I don't understand why the error is "The system cannot fint the specified file". I check the access route with File Explorer of Windows and there is the directory.

Comment: You could delete the folder bin and obj (both in forms and Android project), then clean and rebuild the project .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It didn't work :(

Comment: Post the issue to **Help->Send Feedback->Report a problem** .

Comment: Where do you mean? In Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, post it in IDE->Help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unbelievable. My windows 10 user has an accent mark on the name: Adrián. But the problem was with the path of the project, because I change the name to: Adrian, but the path was still having the accent mark: C:\Users\Adrián. So that is very probably the problem. I know I could change the username from the path, but I think it is a bit difficult than to create a new user, besides, I don't want more problems with another programs installed. I created a new windows user, obviously, without any weird character and then I could work with Xamarin Forms. I think you learn a new thing every day.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue when my project was called Städteam1. I created a new solution and project named Stadteam1 and it works right away. So I guess avoid using any letters that aren't part of standard English in any of the folder or filenames.